# :after element unexpected height behavior

Tags: html, css

Could somebody explain why :after element height depends on top property value?

```
.bar {
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
/* Height of bar match to main element 2px */
.bar:before {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  top: -11px; /* It works */
  background-color: inherit;
  position: absolute;
}
/* Height of bar doesn't match to main element 2px */
.bar:after {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 10px; /* It doesn't work */
  background-color: inherit;
  position: absolute;
}
```

https://codepen.io/konrad9000/pen/wvBawEm

Comment: are you zooming?

Answer (score 0):

I probably know why this is happening. On smaller full HD monitors in windows display setting scale is default set to 125%. Therefore the width of the browser window is also zoomed.

Answer (score -2):

Your position is incorrect in your parent element, .bar

The position has to be relative, not absolute, because the position of your selectors :before and :after depend on the position of .bar

Comment: this is false ... relative or absolute on the parent will change nothing for the childs

Comment: You can absolutely position elements in an absolutely positioned element.